# In Visual Studio Code, autoimport works for recently-opened files only

Tags: visual-studio-code

I work with JavaScript and [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)). When I try to type a name of a module, exported from another file, Visual Studio Code doesn't advise me the module, but if I open the file with an imported module, Visual Studio Code begins to autoimport it well.

Sometimes it's required to resave the file. I have the same problem with automatically changing imports when moving a file. It have the same solution. Is there a buffer or indexation for files in Visual Studio Code or something alike?

Comment: I believe this is because VSCode is using a cache on your workspace, it might work better for you if you only have that folder open, and not others in the file explorer on the left. for instance, in my workspace i have several folders (each containing a different project im working on.) open, so i can easily navigate between them, if you only open one project at a time, i believe itll work better for you.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. You should create file *jsconfig.json* in your project folder and add the following there (it was enough for me):

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: what is your version of vscode?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can configure it in file *hui.pdf*. But it works if you use ikar - a version only with [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) (it works in north Asia, only in Siberia).

You should to find this file and add a string:

```
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
"compilerOptions": [new_reo21]
```

Comment: Re *"it works in north Asia, only in Siberia"*: What do you mean? Can you elaborate?